# How to get ion-select text

Tags: ionic2

I am trying to get the ion-select option's text. Here is my object structure

```
{
"data": [
    {
        "id": "203",
        "bench": "abc"
    },
    {
        "id": "205",
        "bench": "def"
    },
    {
        "id": "207",
        "bench": "ghi"
    }
]}
```

Here is my HTML

```
<ion-select name="bench" formControlName="bench">
                <ion-option *ngFor="let b of benchList" value="{{b.id}}">{{b.bench}}</ion-option>
            </ion-select>
```

How could i get the 'b.bench' . I need both id and bench. I got the id by using value attribute but I can't find a way to get bench value. Please help me with this problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `value` attribute as an object.

```
<ion-select name="bench" formControlName="bench">
                <ion-option *ngFor="let b of benchList" [value]="b">{{b.bench}}</ion-option>
            </ion-select>
```

In the component side:

```
let benchObj = formGroup.controls['bench'].value;
console.log(benchObj.bench)
```