# ion-select default value not loading in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3, ion-select

I've looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40284982/get-ion-select-selected-option?rq=1), [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45419910/ion-select-select-default-value-not-working), and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43204876/how-to-get-ion-select-text?rq=1), but none of them seem to be simple enough for what I'm looking for.

```
<ion-list>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>Select Book</ion-label>
    <ion-select [(ngModel)]="selectbook" value="Return">
      <ion-option value="Hobbit">The Hobbit</ion-option>
      <ion-option value="Fellow">The Fellowship of the Ring</ion-option>
      <ion-option value="Towers">The Two Towers</ion-option>
      <ion-option value="Return" selected="true">The Return of the King</ion-option>
    </ion-select>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>

<ion-item>
  <ion-label>Number of Hobbits</ion-label>
  <ion-input type="number" [(ngModel)]="selecthobbits" [min]="1" [max]="150" value="1"></ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

Then there is a button which (in the `.ts` file) uses `this.selecthobbits` and `this.selectbook`.  But my typescript doesn't seem to be recognizing the default (I get the usual js `undefined`).

I know that this isn't completely failing, because `this.selecthobbits` always gets the right info, and `this.selectbook` does *once someone actually click on an option, even the default*.  So I could go with no default value, but that seems to sort of miss the point of having a default value.

Does anyone know which of the syntaxes I use (I have tried none, both, and each one) for getting a default value that the typescript picks up is correct, or if there is another one?  Frankly, it seems like I might have to import some extra module to access this (e.g. `[value]` versus `value`?), but sifting through these haystacks is a grim prospect. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove `value="Return"` from `ion-select`, and `selected="true"` from `ion-option`, in the `.ts` file in `ionViewDidLoad` or whatever life cycle your are using, write below line

```
this.selectbook = 'Return';
```

option with the value `Return` will be selected on initialization.

Comment: So, in principle this works. (I just put it in the class definition.)  But ... I don't understand why `selected="true"` doesn't work - and apparently is even overridden by this quantity.  And why don't I have to do it for the `ion-input` item?  Is there *any* reliable documentation about this sort of thing?

Comment: E.g. even https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/select/Select/ does not make it 100% obvious, though it is consistent with this answer, so I'll accept it.